# Grooveshark OAuth authentication issue

Tags: oauth, https, grooveshark

I am trying to use the Grooveshark Oauth api for getting an access token. The official documentation says

Simplified OAuth 
We have adopted using a simplified OAuth for Public API integrations. Start by directing users to https://auth.grooveshark.com/ with the GET params of app and callback. The app value should be equal to your API Key. The callback should be a URL that the user can be redirected to upon successful authentication or the user cancelling authentication. One of two possible GET params will be included depending on whether authentication was successful: token when a token is generated successfully and cancel when the user cancels.

I tried using the following url https://auth.grooveshark.com?app=API_KEY&callback=http://www.someurl.com , but I keep on getting the following error

Authorize Access to your Account?
A website is requesting access to your Grooveshark account. However, there was a problem with the request. Please try again.

Any clue on what I maybe doing wrong in forming the OAuth URL?

Comment: I faced the same problem. Have you find a solution?